# making form input unsendable

Tags: html, forms

How can I place editable input in  tag and make it unsendable, is it possible?
Because I want to edit hidden value by using these ones.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To make an input unsendable just remove its' `name` attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="" />
```